# Does filebeat has a module for GCS, where it can send the logs directly to GCS?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, filebeat

The problem statement comprises of running Filebeat as daemon set and sending files to Google cloud Storage bucket.

Through Logstash it is possible, but can Filebeat forward the files to Google cloud Storage bucket.

Comment: As per search, there is no module for Google Cloud Storage for filebeat. Please let me know if anyone has a suggestion towards this problem.

Comment: Would running [gcsfuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) solve your problem? You'd have the bucket mounted locally as part of the filesystem.

Comment: @bramp: Need it on kubernetes master and slave.

Comment: @bramp thiswont solve the problem , mounting

Comment: The only problem here is , we will not be able to retain the logs.

Comment: Maybe a gsutil with oauth and jenkins  job do the trick, initially i  tried with logstash, but that can have a lot of threads and buffers while transfer, dropped that plan.

Answer (score 1):

Filebeat has a [Google Cloud Module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-gcp.html), and even though there is no support for reading from a bucket, you can create a **Pub/Sub service** that will receive the logs, then you can use Filebeat to read it using the "audit" config:

```
- module: googlecloud   
  audit:
    enabled: true
    var.project_id: project-id
    var.topic: es-auditlogs-export
    var.subscription_name: es-auditlogs-export
    var.credentials_file: ${path.config}/gcp-es-service-account.json
```

There is a guide explaining that approach in [here](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/exporting-stackdriver-logging-elasticsearch).